# Maven active profiles source external

Tags: java, maven, configuration, settings, profile

When I try to get the active profiles for my maven project I type:

```
mvn help:active-profiles
```

Just as the documentation states (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
But this is what I get:

```
Active Profiles for Project 'com.mycompany.app:my-app:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT': 

The following profiles are active:

- testProfile (source: external)
```

What does (source: external) mean ? Because I set the profile on the settings.xml file in the .m2 folder, so according to the documentation it should be:

```
(source: settings.xml)
```

Answer (score 1):

The source is where the profile was defined. Source external means that the profile is defined in settings.xml or profiles.xml.

Read [this](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) article. The relevant section is: "***How can I tell which profiles are in effect during a build?***" The sources could be either `pom.xml` of the project, parent project `pom.xml` or maven `settings.xml`.

Comment: The link is the same as the one I posted. But still no where in the article says that there is a "external" option, it only says that the source should be either pom.xml or settings.xml. That is what confuses me, what does it mean with "external" ?

Comment: quote from the answer: "Source external means that the profile is defined in settings.xml or profiles.xml". In the doc search for "Profiles in external files"

Comment: That sounds like it is true, but shouldn't it say "settings.xml" instead of external ? like in the examples.